# How to obtain the value in an array

Tags: javascript

I have a promise object returned by an asynchronous function as it is shown bellow

```
function funcOne(data){
  let myArray = []
  fetch("/upload", {
     "method":"POST",
     "headers":{
        "Content-Type":"application/json; charset=utf-8"
     },
      "body":JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(function(response){
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(data){
         myArray["error"] = data;
    });
    return myArray;
}
```

I want to obtain the stored value in `myArray` inside `funcTwo`

```
function funcTwo(data){
  let value = funcOne(data);
  console.log(value);

}
```

This is the output:

[image: This is the output]

Comment: "I have a promise object returned by" — The value of `myArray` is an array, not a promise.

Comment: The promise result is stored in `myArray`

Comment: That isn't the same thing as "returning a promise" and you don't store the result in that variable until **after** you've returned the original value.

Comment: my issue is not the returned promise but the stored value of the later. I want to obtain the stored value inside `funcTwo`

Comment: You want to use [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) then?

Comment: @Peter Krebs I already have the promise value stored inside `myArray`. what I want is to obtain the stored value in `myArray` inside `funcTwo`. look at the joined image

Comment: I assumed fetch is asynchronous and may not complete immediately. Otherwise you have the output of the array in your image so why don't you simply try to access? It would be `value.error`. Also understand it is not an array technically, it is an object because you give it a named key.